# Power BI Configuración

Tags: powerbi, microsoft

Buen día querida comunidad. Consulta por favor ¿Cómo puedo deshabilitar la opción para bloquear el acceso público a internet en Power BI? Deseo publicar un informe, pero al momento de generar la URL me indica que revise la configuración para publicar en la web, validé esa opción y se encuentra habilitada, pero dentro me sale este mensaje:

> Para habilitar la publicación en la Web, primero debe deshabilitar la opción para bloquear el acceso público a Internet.

Comment: Cuando lo publicas todos lo podran ver, otra manera seria embeberlo en tu aplicativo ahi tendrias que agregarlo logica para realizarlo, te dejo la documentación

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web

Comment: Claro. Pasa que quiero publicarlo a través de Power BI Service (web) para que sea visible para todos. Pero no me permite hacerlo debido al mensaje que me sale en dicha plataforma.

Comment: Puedes agregar alguna imagen descriptiva del error?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/PCh9RHKVOMAH En esta URL está el print de la imagen ya que no me permite agregarla directamente. Ayúdenme por favor.